# This.owner is Null

Tags: c#-4.0

I created an application that interact with a machine in c#(windows application). It contain around more that 10 forms. This project need communication with machine. Here am using serial port communication. Form1 is used for communication. i.e., serial port data received event is present in this form only. At the same time I have to send data to machine also. For this purpose there is a function in form1. I have to send data from all forms like form2,3,4,5..etc when needed. For this purpose I created an object of form1 and called the sending function using this object.. but i cant perform this.

code in form1
for sending data to serial port

```
 public  void  SerialPortValueUpdated(byte[] array)
    {

      serialPort1.Write(array, 0, lm);

     }
```

in form3, form1 function is calling as follows

```
((Form1)this.Owner).SerialPortValueUpdated(ARRAY);
```

But when I go to form2 and come back t form3, this.Owner is empty.. How can I modify this code??. is this function calling method is wrong??

Comment: `.Owner` would only be something if you set it explicitly, like thru the Show() method: `f3.Show(this); // from within Form1`.  If there is only ever **one** instance of Form1, then you could find it in the [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) collection.  Another option would be to create a `static` member in Form1 to hold a reference to itself; initialize that in the Load() event.  Then the other forms could access that value from anywhere.

Comment: can you show an example??

Comment: There can only ever be *one* instance of the Form1 class.  So take advantage of that and add a static `Instance` property to Form1.  Set it in the constructor to `this`.  Now you can simply write Form1.Instance.SerialPortValueUpdated(foo);

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to implement the `static` approach.

Declare a static member in Form1 and initialize it in the Constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public static Form1 Instance = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form1.Instance = this;
    }

    public void SerialPortValueUpdated(byte[] array)
    {

    }

}
```

Now, from any other Form, you can use `Form1.Instance`:

```
Form1.Instance.SerialPortValueUpdated(...);
```